# Vertically combing multiple bar plots

Tags: r, bar-chart, plotly, subplot

I'm trying to use to vertically group bar plots, sharing their x-axes.

I thought of using `R`'s `plotly`'s `subplot` for that but running into an issue I hope someone here may have a solution for.

Here are example data which have 28 groups where I'm creating a bar plot over 4 families in each group and then trying to vertically combine them using `plotly::subplot`:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(group = paste0("G",unlist(lapply(1:28,function(i) rep(i,4)))),
                 family = paste0("F",rep(1:4,28)),
                 log2n = log2(as.integer(runif(4*28,0,30))+1),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Creating the list of bar plots:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

groups <- unique(df$group)
y.range <- c(0,max(df$log2n))
plot.list <- lapply(1:length(groups),function(g){
  group.df <- dplyr::filter(df,group == groups[g])
  plot_ly(x=group.df$family,y=group.df$log2n,type='bar',name=group.df$family,color=group.df$family,showlegend=(g==length(groups))) %>%
    layout(yaxis=list(range=y.range))
})
```

If I try:

```
plotly::subplot(plot.list,shareX=T,nrows=length(plot.list))
```

I get:
[image]

So it seems like some sort of an overflow.

I gradually cut down on the number of plots in `plot.list` that I run `subplot` on and when reached 19 it seemed to stop 'overflowing':

```
plotly::subplot(plot.list[1:19],shareX=T,nrows=19)
```

[image]

Any idea if there's hope to get all 28 bar plots without overflowing?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I would generate the figure with `ggplot` and then convert it to `plotly` (or save it as a picture file) with proper size arguments.

```r
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

g <- ggplot(df, 
       aes(x = family, y = log2n, fill = family)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
    facet_wrap(~group, ncol = 1) +  
    theme_minimal() + 
    theme(legend.position = "none") 

ggsave(g, file = "temp.png", width = 4, height = 40)
ggplotly(g, width = 400, height = 4000)
```